# Unexpected result adding numbers: "79.0014.95", why?

Tags: javascript

So I have a script that grabs a `<tr>` and iterates through it to get all the vars I need using jquery. One of those is a price, where the text of that td is 79.00 So I grab that and store it as var price. I now need to add that to another number that I decide, let's say 14.95. What I thought would work was

```
var val1 = parseInt(price);
val1 = val1.toFixed(2);
var sub = val1 + 14.95;
```

but that outputs 79.0014.95 it's just concatenating them as if it were a string. Here's a the code I am using.

```
$("#phrases tbody tr").live('click', function() {
            var nTds = $('td', this);
            var phrase = $(nTds[0]).text();
            var phrase_id = $(nTds[0]).attr("name");
            var searches = $(nTds[4]).text();
            var price = $(nTds[5]).text(); //is 79.00
            var val1 = parseInt(price);
            val1 = val1.toFixed(2);
            var val2 = 14.95;
            val2 = val2.toFixed(2);
            var sub = val1 + val2;
```

now when sub is output it is 79.0014.95. Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is driving me nuts. Thank you.

Comment: This question reminds me of this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TdrW7.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toFixed()` returns a string.  And `"string" + anything` equals `"stringanything"`.

```
var a = (123).toFixed(2);
var b = a + 123;
console.log(b); // "123.00123"

var c = 123;
var d = c + 123;
console.log(d.toFixed(2)); // "246.00"
```

So do the `toFixed()` *after* you add the numbers together, not before.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ OP is adding two results of `toFixed()`.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ It caught me out too, actually :/

Comment: You will, but doing money math properly is another topic altogether :)

Answer (score 1):

`Number.toFixed()` method formats the number and returns its **string** representation.

JavaScript's `+` operator does concatenation whenever **at least one** of the operands is a string.

You should do formatting once all arithmetic has been performed.

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operator will do string concatenation if either operand is a string. The [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method returns a *string* representation of a number. Hence the result you are getting.

You need to do your calculations first and then call `toFixed()` on the final result.

Also, why are you using `parseInt()` when dealing with prices that could (presumably) have something other than 0 after the decimal point? You probably need `parseFloat()`, or you can convert a string to a number using the unary + operator (`var n = (+"123.32");`).

Answer (score 0):

`toFixed()` returns a string.

Do the padding after you do the math.